# string manipulation in FORTRAN: strange behavior

Tags: fortran, gfortran

If the input of the following working example ist - for example - "ach_40", the output is "ach_40.DOC?" and "ach_40.IMG". Where is the "?" coming from?

The code is:

```
   program test

   character*8 filin
   character*12 dummy,file1,file2
   character*4  :: img = '.IMG', doc='.DOC'
   integer*4 ls1, ls2, i

   write(*,*) ' File (without extension): '
   read(*,'(a8)') filin

c   first file

   dummy=filin // doc

   ls1 = len_trim(dummy)
   ls2=0
   do i = 1,ls1
     if(dummy(i:i).ne.' ') then
       ls2=ls2+1
       file1(ls2:ls2) = dummy(i:i)
     endif
   enddo

c      second file

   dummy=filin // img

   ls1 = len_trim(dummy)
   ls2=0
   do i = 1,ls1
     if(dummy(i:i).ne.' ') then
       ls2=ls2+1
       file2(ls2:ls2) = dummy(i:i)
     endif
   enddo

   write(*,*) file1
   write(*,*) file2

   stop
   end
```

Thanks a lot for your hint!!

Comment: Bearing in mind that a) a fixed length string in Fortran always has that same fixed length; and b) if you don't define a variable, it's value is undefined, run through the logic of your program with your example input, and consider "What should I expect the value of the last few characters in `file1` to be?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never set the value of the whole `file1` and `file2` so the characters, which you do not explicitly set to something, can be anything.

At the beginning you can set initialize the strings as

```
file1 = ''
file2 = ''
```

and they will be filled with spaces which is what you need.

---

But you probably just want:

```
file1 = trim(filin) // doc
file2 = trim(filin) // img
```

instead all of that complicated code.